# SharePoint 2013 Patching Update

Tags: sharepoint

My SharePoint Farm is currently running with version 15.0.4849.1000 (CU - August 9, 2016). Now I want to install the recently CU of SharePoint 2013 (version 15.0.5172.1000 - September 2019).

Can I install the latest CU without installing the others CU.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates#sharepoint-2013-update-history.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could installed the latest CU directly. No other cu is required to patch SharePoint. Each new release contains all the hotfixes and security updates that were included with the previous Microsoft SharePoint  2013 update package releases.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475610/september-10-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb4